# How to sort list of strings by custom rules in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I want use R to sort a list of `c("ABC-L1","DEF-L2","XYZ-B12","AAA-B1")`, in a order that with `/-([LB])(\d+)/`, first by `$1`, and then by `$2`.

Which means, I need the order `c("AAA-B1","XYZ-B12","ABC-L1","DEF-L2")`.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`:

```
vec <- c("ABC-L1","DEF-L2","XYZ-B12","AAA-B1")

vec[order(sub('^[A-Z]+-', '', vec))]

# [1] "AAA-B1"  "XYZ-B12" "ABC-L1"  "DEF-L2"
```

`sub` removes everything upto `-`, we then `order` the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The following does what you want.

```
x <- c("ABC-L1","DEF-L2","XYZ-B12","AAA-B1")


sp <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, "-"))
inx <- order(sp[, 2], sp[, 1])

x[inx]
#[1] "AAA-B1"  "XYZ-B12" "ABC-L1"  "DEF-L2"
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_plit to separate by "-" and then order by columns

```
  text <- c("ABC-L1","DEF-L2","XYZ-B12","AAA-B1")

  text<- t(as.data.frame(str_split(text, "-")))
  res <- text[order(text[, 2], text[, 1]),]
```